# Canada - how long can a person be under investigation?

Tags: criminal-law, canada

I have been accused of a crime, and the police informed me of such. However, I have not been charged. They have told my lawyer that I am under investigation but haven't given any more info.

Is there any limit as to how long I can be "under investigation" for until either I must be charged or the investigation has to be dropped? Further, would the police be obligated to inform me if the investigation ended, or would I just hear nothing?

I ask because this process is causing me a lot of stress and I'd like to know how long it can go on for.

Answer (score 2):

If the crime is a summary conviction offence you must be charged within 6 months of the act.

For indictable (serious) offences there is no limit other than the practical one of before you die.

The police are under no obligation to inform you of the status of their investigation and you can rest assured that they only told you they were investigating you in order to further the investigation in some way.

Sorry about your stress.